# Google Maps: InfoWindow closing after auto pan

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a map with a bunch of markers, and a table of data that corresponds to each marker. When the user clicks on an item in the table, the `InfoWindow` for the corresponding marker is opened. Everything works fine when the map is zoomed out and the markers are all visible, but if the map is zoomed in, and an `InfoWindow` for an off-screen marker is opened by clicking the item in the table, here is what happens:

1. The map scrolls to the correct location, where the `InfoWindow` already appears open
2. The map stops panning, and the `InfoWindow` disappears.

Any suggestions as to what might be going on and how to solve this?

Comment: Could you replicate the behavior in a jsfiddle? If you disable auto-pan and pan there manually does it stay open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, the issue related to the fact that I was using the [Marker Clusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/) on the map... essentially, the following was happening:

1. Click item in table, `InfoWindow` opens
2. Map gets panned to the location to display the `InfoWindow`
3. When panning is complete, the Marker Clusterer was then re-drawing (if needed), and forcing the `InfoWindow` closed.

My solution was that when an item in the table is clicked, I get the corresponding `Marker's` latlng, manually pan to this location, wait for the panning to complete via the 'idle' listener, and when complete (and the Clusterer has done it's re-draw), THEN I open the `InfoWindow`.

```
// get map, marker positions
var mapLatLng = GLOBAL_map.getCenter();    
var markerLatLng = GLOBAL_markers[index].getPosition();

// pan the map
if(!markerLatLng.equals(mapLatLng)) {
  // map will need to pan
  GLOBAL_map.panTo(markerLatLng);
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GLOBAL_map, 'idle', function() {
    // open InfoWindow
    GLOBAL_infowindow.setContent(GLOBAL_markers_content[index]);
    GLOBAL_infowindow.open(GLOBAL_map, GLOBAL_markers[index]);
  });
} else {
  // map won't be panning, which wouldn't trigger 'idle' listener
  GLOBAL_infowindow.setContent(GLOBAL_markers_content[index]);
  GLOBAL_infowindow.open(GLOBAL_map, GLOBAL_markers[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This drove me crazy. My solution is simpler, though. I just set a timer so I don't refresh the map within one second after a pin is clicked.

start with the global:

```
// global timer variable
var clickTime = Date.now() - 1001;
```

then define you marker click like:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

    clickTime = Date.now();
});
```

then set up your idle like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
    if (Date.now() > (clickTime + 1000))
        updateMap();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `idle` event. Use `dragend` and `zoom_changed` events from the [API spec](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) instead which will allow you to open your infoBoxes without refreshing the map.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
    getMarkers();   
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    getMarkers();   
});
```